# Securing vertical hinge

Tags: building, snot

[image]

In this construction, I want the vertical hinge to be in this location, centered in a 3 brick wide area. On top of it is two plates and layer of studs that match the 5:2 ratio, so in theory the hinge would be secure in this 3 brick wide gap. Is there a more elegant way of securing both sides of the hinge? I've looked at some bracket pieces but the issue is that they all have studs on top rather than stud-holes.

Comment: FYI, "stud-hole" is better know as "anti-stud"

Answer (score 2):

I would remove last two plates since they ruin the geometry here. And instead I can suggest using any modified brick with two studs facing towards hinged brick (white colored bricks). [Technic, Pin Connector Round 2/3 L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18654#T=C) (seen in red) could then be used to attach studs on both sides. Orange plate below confirms all of this fit in required space.

[image]

A bit of background on the logic with my solution. With cases like this it is helpful when you measure everything in standard units. Here, brick height is 6 units, plate height is 2 units and stud is 5 units. From here you can clearly see you have a gap of 3 studs=15 units and your assembly is 14 units. The difference in 1 unit makes things more complicated. So my suggestion is to simplify it and make use of more common pieces.

Comment: the assembly is 7 plates (14 units) + stud height (1 unit) is 15 units

Comment: @qwr stud height is tiny bit more than 1 unit. And it is also irrelevant here.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? I want it to fit in the 3 stud space. I also found that a technic liftarm is the right width (8 units)

Comment: For example, you don't count stud height into geometry when building a wall. Stud is just here for connection. And Technic liftarm is square in cross-section, which means it is 5 units wide/high - same width as a 1x1 brick

Comment: Are you sure it's square? It seems slightly narrower in width than height.

Comment: @qwr Modern Technic is build around cube shape dimensions - so single bushing, or 1L connector suggested in the answer is same size in all dimensions. Technic brick isn't though since it is a based on the usual brick with 5*5*6 units in size.